# Cant get connection with Socket.IO from Angular to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to solve this for hours.. if someone can help me.
I cant understand why this doenst emit or receive the message.

At angular I got this error:

```
http://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NEhK-JT 404
```

4200 is the PORT of my Angular Application and 8080 from my server.

NodeJS:

```
// Define Porta
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server Online - ' + port);
});

// Socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log(`${socket.id} is connected`);
    socket.on('room', function (room) {
        console.log('room', room)
        socket.join(room);
    });
});
```

Angular 9:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'
public socket
public orgId: string = '123abc'

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setupSocketConnection();
  }

  chat(nome: string, avatar: number, mensagem: string) {
    io.connect(this.orgId).emit('organizacao', {
      nome: nome,
      mensagem: mensagem,
      avatar: avatar,
    });
  }

  setupSocketConnection() {
    this.socket = io.connect(`http://localhost:8080`, { 
      reconnectionDelay: 1000,
      reconnection: true,
      reconnectionAttempts: 10,
      transports: ['websocket'],
      agent: false, 
      upgrade: false,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    });
  }
```

From my Console.log at Server

```
zEnR7Cp23zcur4_kAAAH is connected
86sIiMA8vRZEN-WcAAAI is connected
SU4K2n9jAx_UO2ndAAAJ is connected
UAwlMpNiZWhw_eo9AAAK is connected
K6myruVum4FPKTeLAAAL is connected
Z5QULdZtdsRo5gC1AAAM is connected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to implement `rooms` then please read https://socket.io/docs/rooms/

For your case what I can see here is that on server-side you are listening to the event named `room` and on client-side you are emitting to `organizacao` and also you need to use the `socket` object instead of `io`, refer from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

```
socket.connect(this.orgId).emit('room', {
      nome: nome,
      mensagem: mensagem,
      avatar: avatar,
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.
When i change to socket, nothing happens.

Comment: have you changed  `organizacao` to `room` ?